# Can't get the tail to wag (animate) in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hey if anybody can please help me animate this object :

Up - Down To Move  |
Left - Right to Rotate  |
a to look up   |
z to look down

Link to orignal file : http://www.aacctrust.org/anim/anim.htm

JSON Model File (with animation tail-wag):

http://wikisend.com/download/654748/wolf.json

The problem is the json model file has been provided with necessary details regarding the animation of the tail. The tail of the wolf is suppose to wag.
But it doesnot , I have tried everything but to no help .

Is something wrong in the code or am I not exporting properly frm Blender.

Below is the code :

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>  
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>


   <script src="three.js"></script>

    <script>

     var scene = new THREE.Scene();
     var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvas });
     var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, (canvas.width / canvas.height) , 1, 10000 );
     var clock  = new THREE.Clock(),mixer;
     var forest,wolf,animation;            
     var fwd,bck,lft,rgt,up,down = 0 ;
     var action = {};

    camera.fov *= 0.3;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();            

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    renderer.setClearColor (0x22222222, 1);

    camera.position.z = 28;

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map:       THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('wolf_uvcons.png') } );
    // Wolf Texture Above # Forest Uses Local Materials @Blender

    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

    loader.load('forest.json', function(geometry, materials) {
               forest = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new   THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
               forest.scale.x = forest.scale.y = forest.scale.z = 0.25;
               forest.rotateX( Math.PI / 2 );forest.rotateZ( Math.PI  );           //load :env:
                forest.translation = THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
                scene.add(forest);
        });




    loader.load('wolf.json', function(geometry, materials) {
       wolf = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry,material);
       wolf.scale.x = wolf.scale.y = wolf.scale.z = 0.25;                  //load wolf
       wolf.translation = THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
       scene.add(wolf);
       wolf.add(camera);
       wolf.translateY(-27); /// Bring it down
       wolf.translateZ(100); /// Bring it down

      action.idle  = new THREE.AnimationAction(geometry.animations[ 0 ]);         
      action.idle.weight  = 1;

  // Create animation mixer and pass object to it
      mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(wolf);
      mixer.addAction( action.idle );

      });


    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFFFF,1);
    scene.add(light);
    var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffcccc,0.41 );
    pointLight.position.set( 0, 100, 3 );
    scene.add( pointLight );
    var pointLight1 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xff0000,0.81 );
    pointLight1.position.set( 100, 200, 3 );
    scene.add( pointLight1 );

    function moveWolf()
    {

        if (fwd==1)
        { wolf.translateZ(-1);}
        if (bck==1)
        { wolf.translateZ(1);}
        if (lft==1)
        { wolf.rotateY(Math.PI/200)}
        if (rgt==1)
        { wolf.rotateY(-Math.PI/200);}
        if (up==1)
        { camera.rotateX(Math.PI/200);}
        if (down==1)
        { camera.rotateX(-Math.PI/200);}

      }

    function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    moveWolf();
    render();

    var delta = clock.getDelta();
    var theta = clock.getElapsedTime();

    if ( mixer ) { mixer.update( delta ); }
 }

 function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
  }

   animate();
</script>

<script>
document.onkeydown = checkKey1;
document.onkeyup = checkKey2;

function checkKey1(e) {

e = e || window.event;

if (e.keyCode == '38') {
    // up arrow
    fwd=1;
}
else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
    // down arrow
    bck=1;
}
else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
   // left arrow
   lft=1;
}
else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
   // right arrow
   rgt=1;
}
else if (e.keyCode == '65') {
   up=1;
}
else if (e.keyCode == '90') {
   down=1;
}
}


function checkKey2(e) {

e = e || window.event;

if (e.keyCode == '38') {
    // up arrow
    fwd=0;
}
else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
    // down arrow
    bck=0;
}
else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
   // left arrow
   lft=0;
}
else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
   // right arrow
   rgt=0;
}
else if (e.keyCode == '65') {
   // right arrow
   up=0;
}
else if (e.keyCode == '90') {
   // right arrow
   down=0;
}

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE :

During the process of waiting for a reply I went on a self-exploration trip ;)

And found a nearly acceptable solution , steps are aa follows :

1. File >> Export >> Wavefront (OBJ)
2. Ensure that Animation is checked as option .
3. Click export (while exporting plz do it in a separate folder as no of files could be large depending on the number of frames.)
4. Copy the folder in Blender > Python > Bin directory.
5. Copy convertor from three.js utils OBJ for python3 to Blender > Python > Bin directory.
6. Launch command prompt in Admin mode and run the following command :

python objtothreejs_conv_python3 -i meshdirname\meshname_000001.obj -o output.js -m "meshdirname\meshname_*.obj"

Output Animation would be morph animation and would require some changes in the mixer for playing MorphAnims.